# Order Objects using an associated model and timedelta

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a puzzle on my hands. As an exercise, I am trying to write a queryset that helps me visualize which of my professional contacts I should prioritize corresponding with.

To this end I have a couple of models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    target_contact_interval = models.IntegerField(default=45)

class ContactInstance(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='contacts')
    date = models.DateField()
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The column `target_contact_interval` on the `Person` model generally specifies the maximum amount of days that should pass before I reach out to this person again.

A `ContactInstance` reflects a single point of contact with a `Person`. A `Person` can have a reverse relationship with many `ContactInstance` objects.

So, the first `Person` in the queryset should own the greatest difference between the `date` of the most recent `ContactInstance` related to it and its own `target_contact_interval`

So my dream function would look something like:

```
Person.objects.order_by(contact__latest__date__day - timedelta(days=F(target_contact_interval))
```

but of course that won't work for a variety of reasons.

I'm sure someone could write up some raw PostgreSQL for this, but I am really curious to know if there is a way to accomplish it using only the Django ORM.

Here are the pieces I've found so far, but I'm having trouble putting them together.

I might be able to use a [`Subquery`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) to annotate the date of the most recent datapoint:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
latest = ContactInstance.objects.filter(person=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date')
Person.objects.annotate(latest_contact_date=Subquery(latest.values('date')[:1]))
```

And I like the idea of sorting the [null values at the end](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-to-sort-null-values):

```
from django.db.models import F
Person.objects.order_by(F('last_contacted').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

But I don't know where to go from here. I've been trying to put everything into `order_by()`, but I can't discern if it is possible to use `F()` with annotated values or with `timedelta` in my case.

UPDATE:
I have changed the `target_contact_interval` model to a `DurationField` as suggested. Here is the query I am attempting to use:

```
ci = ContactInstance.objects.filter(
    person=OuterRef('pk')
).order_by('-date')

Person.objects.annotate(
    latest_contact_date=Subquery(ci.values('date'[:1])
).order_by((
    (datetime.today().date() - F('latest_contact_date')) - 
    F('target_contact_interval')
).desc(nulls_last=True))
```

It seems to me that this should work, however, the queryset is still not ordering correctly.

Comment: Its good to use [`DurationField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) for **`target_contact_interval`**

Comment: Thank you for the tip. That has helped a lot